# How to sent information between procecces in C using fork

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the prime factors of a number (x for exemple) using fork()

In the child proces I want to iterate form 2 to x/2-1 and see witch number divides x. But i don't know how to let the parent proces to know that I modified a variable inside the child porces

And now my question is.. how do i sent information for child to parent?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int var = 0;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid > 0){
      if(var = 0){
         var++;
      else{do nothing}
else if(pid == 0){
  printf("%d\n", var);           here the program will print 0 but i want it to print 1. How?
}
}
}

}
```

Comment: This is called *interprocess communication (IPC)* and there are many mechanisms available.  One common choice is a pipe.

Comment: Pipes, unix domain sockets, signals, posix or sysv message queues, heck even shared memory. There are entire books written on the subject of available IPC mechanisms.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `if(var = 0){
         var++;
      else{do nothing}`  the `else`  code block can be completely removed

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  First because it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files and because `do nothing` is not a valid C statemetn

Comment: OT: the function: `fork()` returns three kinds of values: <0 means an error occurred.   ==0 means in the child process.  >0 means in the parent process. Your code needs to handle all three conditions to be robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. checks for (and handles) errors
4. documents why each header is included
5. demonstrates one interprocess communication (IPC)  method (pipes)
6. demonstrates good use of horizontal and vertical spacing for readability and ease of understanding
7. uses `int main( void )` so no warning messages from the compiler about unused parameters
8. used braces '{' and '}' in body of `case 0:` and `default` code blocks so can have local variables within those code blocks

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), perror()
#include <sys/types.h>// pid_t
#include <unistd.h>   // fork(), pipe(), read()
#include <sys/wait.h> // wait()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE

enum { READ_FROM, WRITE_TO };

int main( void )  
{
    int status; 

    int fd[2];
    if( pipe( fd ) )
    {
        perror( "pipe failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    switch( pid )
    {
        case -1:
            perror( "fork failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

        case 0: // child process
        {
            int var = 1;
            ssize_t bytesWritten;
            close( fd[ READ_FROM ] );

            if( ( bytesWritten = write( fd[ WRITE_TO ], &var, sizeof( var ) ) ) != sizeof( int ) )
            {
                perror( "write failed" );
                close( fd[ WRITE_TO ] );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            close( fd[ WRITE_TO ] );
            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        }

        default: // parent process
        {
            int buffer = 0;
            ssize_t bytesRead;
            close( fd[ WRITE_TO ] );

            if( ( bytesRead = read( fd[ READ_FROM ], &buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) ) != sizeof( int ) )
            {
                perror( "read failed" );
                close( fd[ READ_FROM ] );
                wait( &status );  // waits for child to exit
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            printf( "%d\n", buffer );       
            close( fd[ READ_FROM ] );
            wait( &status );  // waits for child to exit
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

A typical/successful run of the program results in

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, every elegant. Could you explain me what you did in those if statements and the wait( &status)? Will it work for more children too?

Comment: the `wait()` is do the parent does not exit before the child.  Yes, this will work with multiple child processes.  One `wait()` needed for each child process.  If you want to `wait` for a specific child process, then use `waitpid()`.  The `status` variable will receive both the exit value from the child AND several other bits of related information.  The MAN page for `wait()` explains the other information

Comment: regarding: `if( ( bytesRead = read( fd[ READ_FROM ], &buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) ) != sizeof( int ) )`  This performs the same functionality as the call to `write()`, but reading instead

Comment: using: if( ( bytesWritten = write( fd[ WRITE_TO ], &var, sizeof( var ) ) ) != sizeof( int ) ) as an example: this calls function: write() to write the contents of var, for the length of var to the pipe. The function: write() returns the number of bytes written and the third parameter indicates how many of those entities to send. so the if() is checking the returned value to assure if the desired number of entities were sent, If not, then output both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr` via the call to `perror()`